# Ruby Rails find ip address in a range from low and high fields in db table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a database table containing 7000 records with low and high ip address and I'm using the Rails `IPAaddr` class.

If my `request.remote_ip` is found in the table's `low` or `high` fields, I get the `low` and `high` and put them into the `IPAddr` from the query then run it and I get a `true`. Now I'm asked that if the `remote_ip` address doesn't exist in table but it falls into the low and high ip address range in the table to also get a `true`.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using, i.e. MySQL/Postgres/MariaDB?
And what datatype is the IP Address column being stored as?

Comment: Postgres ip address fields are string

Answer (score 1):

Its actual relatively simple with Postgres built in [`inet` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-net-types.html):

```rb
Thing.where(
  "inet ? << any(array[things.low, things.high]::inet[])", ip_address
)
```

This tests if the passed ip address is contained within the upper and lower bounds. The `inet` function casts to the inet type. The Ruby equivilent is:

```
IpAddr.new(low)..IpAddr.new(high).cover?(IpAddr.new(ip_address))
```

Comment: Did you mean something like this: SELECT start_ip_address, end_ip_address FROM "us_ip_addresses" WHERE (INET ? <<any (array[us_ip_addresses.start_ip_address, us_ip_addresses.end_ip_address]::inet[]) , '207.146.0.0')

Comment: How am I supposed to know? Your question is missing any kind of information about your schema.

Comment: Can you please do it properly by editing your question?

Comment: table name us_ip_addresses fields start_ip_address as low, end_ip_address as high remote_ip = 206.0.1.1 in the  range of start_ip_address = 206.0.0.0 - end_ip_address = 206.1.255.255 fields are string

Comment: Max I gave you the db schema. I been trying but dont have the right postgresql syntax : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "any"